# How do you create a custom popup window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am fairly new to Android and I am currently working on an app which has a feed where users can create new posts (something like facebook). When the user clicks on the FAB , I want to show a popup window with a custom layout. Something like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I feel like this is something that can be done with fragments. All I need is some direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks like a `Dialog` or a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: Have to agree with CommonsWare, that seems like a task for dialog.  For example, I have several coloring book apps, that do something very similar to what you're trying (picking a specific color, a new canvas, etc...) and they all use custom dialogs.... try this link http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/7426-android-adventures-custom-dialogs-using-dialogfragment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inflate your layout as below

```
  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.congratulations_dialog, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);

    ImageView image1 = view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    TextView txtSuccess = view.findViewById(R.id.txtSuccess);
    ImageView btnCancle = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancle);
    Button btnContinue = view.findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);

    txtSuccess.setText("string");
    btnContinue.setText("string");

    btnCancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: 7/5/18 your click listener  
        }
    });
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: 7/5/18 your click listener
        }
    });

    alertDialogCongratulations = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialogCongratulations.show();
    alertDialogCongratulations.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);//
```